# xkb: editing keyboard layout/map in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I edited the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fi` but I can't take those modifications into use.

The folder `/var/lib/xkb` is empty apart of the file `README.compiled` which contains this:

> The X server uses this directory to store the compiled version of the
>   current keymap and/or any scratch keymaps used by clients.  The X server
>   or some other tool might destroy or replace the files in this directory,
>   so it is not a safe place to store compiled keymaps for long periods of
>   time.  The default keymap for any server is usually stored in:
>        X-default.xkm
>   where  is the display number of the server in question, which makes
>   it possible for several servers *on the same host* to share the same 
>   directory.
>
> Unless the X server is modified, sharing this directory between servers on
>   different hosts could cause problems.

So I suppose this folder should contain the compiled xkm file, but in the filesystem there is no xkm files anywhere.

How can I take my modifications into use?

**Update, a little progress:**

I added this to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fi`:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
   xkb_symbols "oma2" {

   include "fi(kotoistus)"

   key <AE00> { [  braceleft,       braceright,       NoSymbol,              NoSymbol              ] };
   name[Group1]="Finnish (oma2)";
};
```

And this to evdev.xml:

```
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>oma2</name>
        <description>Finnish (oma2)</description>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
```

I can now select the new variant Finnish (oma2), but I can't still see any change in the actual keyboard. I believe/hope I added the new definition correctly...

Comment: Did you add a new variant, or did you edit an existing variant? In case of the latter, rebooting ought to help.

Comment: I tried both, first edit the existing (fi), then added my own. No effect to anything. I couldn't even see the new variant in keyboard layout list ("Text entry").

What's going on here? Where are the compiled files?

Comment: A new variant needs to be added to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`.

Comment: Maybe try to use `<TLDE>` instead of `<AE00>`.

Comment: Now it works :) Thank you. If you want to add an answer below with the most important points, I could make it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Good! There are several answers on this topic already, and I don't think this adds anything of general interest, so I voted for your question to be considered a duplicate instead.